# (Security Problem)Is there any way to hide dbus method call from monitoring dbus?

Tags: security, passwords, monitor, dbus

Please understand that I'm not good at english.

I developed an authenticate system consists of several processes, using dbus to communicate each other.

I just found out that every single communication through dbus can be watched using dbus-monitor. Such ac password and id. I just want it to be hidden.

Using dbus private connection, it can be hidden because doesn't go through dbus-daemon. But private connection is kind of complicate and dirty work.

So, is there any way to hide dbus communication using dbus open connection (not private connection)?

Sorry for scrambled paragraphs again. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3):

> I just found out that every single communication through dbus can be
> watched using dbus-monitor. Such ac password and id. I just want it to
> be hidden.

This is not the case: `policykit` rules still apply. For example as non-privileged user I can't monitor `wpa_supplicant` :

```
dbus-monitor  --system interface=fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.Network
dbus-monitor: unable to enable new-style monitoring: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: "Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.6957" (uid=1002 pid=206438 comm="dbus-monitor --system interface=fi.w1.wpa_supplica") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Monitoring" member="BecomeMonitor" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.DBus" (bus)". Falling back to eavesdropping.
signal time=1600511999.087722 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.6957 serial=2 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameAcquired
   string ":1.6957"
```

because of the `policykit`-rules:

```
<!DOCTYPE busconfig PUBLIC
 "-//freedesktop//DTD D-BUS Bus Configuration 1.0//EN"
 "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/busconfig.dtd">
<busconfig>
        <policy user="root">
                <allow own="fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1"/>

                <allow send_destination="fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1"/>
                <allow send_interface="fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1"/>
                <allow receive_sender="fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1" receive_type="signal"/>
        </policy>
        <policy context="default">
                <deny own="fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1"/>
                <deny send_destination="fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1"/>
                <deny receive_sender="fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1" receive_type="signal"/>
        </policy>
</busconfig>
```

Of course `root` can read all your data anyway.

If you are worried about the data appearing in log files, you can pass data using a Unix file descriptor (type signature `h`). So the data is opaque to the user of `dbus-monitor`

Answer (score 0):

> So, is there any way to hide dbus communication using dbus open connection (not private connection)?

No, there is not.

`dbus-monitor` requires privileges to run, and so there should be no need to be worried about secrets leaking.

Comment: thanks a lot!
anyway, i have to find other solution